# Return home after calling a reactjs function

Tags: reactjs

i have an application with 4 components,App that is the home and others 3 Show,Edit and Create.

In Show there is a function that delete a record from a table in App,

```
delete(id){
     firebase.firestore().collection('boards').doc(id).delete().then(() => {
         console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
         this.props.history.push("/")
     }).catch((error) => {
         console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
         });
  }
```

in Edit and Create the onSubmit metod modify the table.

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { title, description, author, id } = this.state;

    this.ref.add({
        title,
        description,
        author,
        id
    }).then((docRef) => {
        this.setState({
        title: '',
        description: '',
        author: '',
        id: ''
        });
        this.props.history.push("/")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
  });
}
```

I want to go back home after calling delete and onSubmit,what i can do?

Comment: It seems like there is essential information missing. How far do you live from where you are currently at?

Comment: Aren't you already navigating to `/`?

Comment: How to navigate to `/` from  a function? @mgarcia

Comment: What is `this.props.history.push("/")` doing?

Comment: Don't know i forked from Github.